# Mouse over: text on image and link -- HTML solution

Tags: image, url, text, hover, mouseover

I get this situation: a picture that turns into a color transparent layer plus a little text information when mouse over. Now, I wanted that to be clickable, i.e. to link it to some url. How can I do it, just by adding some plain and simple HTML code into it?

Here's the code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.pic2 {
    width:220px;
    height:220px;
    background:url(http://www.delish.com/cm/delish/images/Fh/chianti-tuscany-vineyard-lg.jpg) no-repeat;
}
.text {
    width:170px;
    height:170px;
    background:#803244;
    opacity:0;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-transform: uppercase
}
.pic2:hover .text {
    opacity:0.8;
    text-align:left;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:100;
    font-family:"Arial", Sans serif;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

Tincidunt reprimique no pro eius adipiscing mea ne, mea dicant elaboraret ea, mei meis soleat splendide ea duo latine num quam at lorem ipsum.

http://jsfiddle.net/luizpaulorocha/5xk2wa4h/

Answer (score 0):

I saw it's a `div` which is hidden initially and on hover is shown.

The easiest thing which you can do is to add an `anchor` and give `href`.

Like this:

```
<div class="pic2">
    <div class="text">
        <a href="#">Tincidunt reprimique no pro eius adipiscing mea ne, mea dicant elaboraret ea, mei meis soleat splendide ea duo latine num quam at lorem ipsum.</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Nice, Hassaan! Half job done. :) But the thing is... now I just get the TEXT as a link. And I wanted ALL the element, I mean, the TEXT and the SQUARE AREA -- actually a transparent layer over the photo. How to turn that square (also) into a linkable element?...

Comment: you just need to deal with opacity and z-index properties of css

Comment: tryed add/change opacity and z-index. not working. is there any way to give href propertie to the whole thing (the square area and text)?